# HANA Cloud Portal widget creation using SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create two widgets that use `<sap-context>` feature for HANA Cloud Portal using SAPUI5 framework.

The problem is that I cannot find any tutorials/examples of using mvc model for widget creation. Every example I have found till now uses SAPUI5 inside `<script>` tag in html file as if it's jquery or javascript.

Is it possible at all to create widgets using mvc model at all? If it is, links for examples/tutorials would help me alot.

**NB:**

As a matter of fact, I did try to use mvc model, but when I try to call a function using the following syntax:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId('<view-name-here>').getController().publish("<key-name-here>", "<value-here>");
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getController' of undefined` error. I'm not sure what causes this error - is it a flaw in my code or the fact that there is no 'core' if I don't build SAPUI5 application... (I'm still new to this SAPUI5 thing)

Thank you.

Comment: Open your 'Network' tab in the Developer tools of your Browser and check where the framework is looking for the view. It seems that the framework fails in finding and loading it. This usually happens if there´s no ressource mapping done (e.g. with `jQuery.sap.registerModulePath()`) which results in an invalid lookup for the view.

Comment: @TimGerlach Thank you for the tip. I created the required widget without using mcv model, just one script file.